# How do I pass a function with an argument of a structure passed by reference?

Tags: c++, function, data-structures

I was working on my program and noticed that it doesn't compile. I was wondering why I can't pass my structure array as an array of references. My code is down below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct a{
        int name;
};
void input(a & array1[10]){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                array1[i].name=i+1;
        }
}

void print(a & array1[10]){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                cout<<array1[i].name<<endl;
        }
}
int main(){ 
        a array1[10];
        input(array1[10]);
        print(array1[10]);
}
```

Comment: You have an array of objects. What would allow that to become an array of references? (You can have a reference to an array of objects, but the things in the array do not change.)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax to pass the array by reference is wrong.

Please see the working code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct a{
        int name;
};
void input(a  (&array1)[10]){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                array1[i].name=i+1;
        }
}

void print(a (&array1)[10]){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                cout<<array1[i].name<<endl;
        }
}
int main(){ 
        a array1[10];
        input(array1); // make sure you simply pass the array name
        print(array1);
}
```

[Try it out yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/dFUf8K)

As enforced by the syntax of the language parenthesis that enclose array1 as in `(&array1)` are necessary. If you don't use them you're simply passing *an array of reference* **not a referene to an array**.

`array1[10]` is the 10th element of the array(which actually in your case doesn't exists, it's simply out-of-array-bound access), instead you need to pass the address of the first element of the array which is the same as array name i.e. the array name decays to a pointer.

Comment: Did you mean 11th element?

Comment: @Incomputable Well, this is C++. Index starts from 0. By 10th element I meant the element at the 10th index which according to you is 11th element.

Comment: @aep In my experience, most C++ people would not refer to `array1[10]` as the tenth element because, as you noted, the index start from zero. Rather, they would call it either the eleventh element of the array (since `array1[0]` is the first element) or element number 10 (using the index value).

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array into a function:

- **<opinion>** The array degrades to a pointer.  So you might as well have the
  function declare the parameter as a pointer, `"a*"`, instead of as an
  array, `a[]`.
- The function has no idea how many items are in the array parameter.  You should get in the habit of passing "size" as a parameter to a function when you pass the array.

  - On the flip side, arrays passed as pointers are inherently a reference parameter not a value (copy of) parameter. So you are implicitly meeting your goal of passing your array and all the items in the array by reference.

This is probably what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct a {
    int name;
};

void input(a* array, size_t count){
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        array[i].name = i + 1;
    }
}

void print(a* array, size_t count) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        cout<<array[i].name<<endl;
    }
}
int main() { 
    a array1[10] = {};  // zero-init the array of a's
    input(array1, 10);
    print(array1, 10);
}
```